# BigQuery WebUI (Forbidden Error 403)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wanna find out why I got the attached error when I tried and opened the BigQuery WebUI from the Google Cloud Console. The irony is that I got no issues working on the BigQuery via Google Cloud Shell or Google Cloud SDK on my Linux Workstation. I am checking with Google Cloud Support Team too. Still on going. I will appreciate your thoughts and ideas and suggestions on this. I will keep you posted too if Google Support has made it first.

NOTE to self:

I am not really forbidden to the BigQuery Service in general but I just can't use the BigQuery WebUI. And that is strange for me.

And it is not listed at [Big Query Troubleshooting Errors Page as well.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors)

[BigQuery WebUI Forbidden Error 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJySE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an authorization error. Check that you have the BigQuery API enabled. Check that you have the appropriate roles in IAM. Try giving "BigQuery Admin" role to your user {1}.

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Comment: I will check but I can work on it from the cloud shell. I just can't use the webui. A strange auth error.